# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in compiling android app in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to use IntelliJ IDE 13 for developing an Android app, whenever i make a new project and try to compile it i get this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodErro

I have tried another SDKs but nothing has changed.

the picture of error is attached.

Please help me :([My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2euz.png)

Comment: post your code then..

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are using some method which is not available in the current API level which you are using. See more about [NoSuchMethodError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)